# how to construct a formula with an opposite SAT value of another one

Tags: complexity-theory, logic

given a formula S (that is built of binary variables and "or", "not", "and" gates).
IS there a polynomial algorithim that builds S' that satisfies:
S' satisfied if and only if S doesn't satisfied.
which means: S' is in SAT if and only if S not in SAT

Comment: Did you mean *satisfied* or *satisfiable*?

Answer (score 9):

The existence of such an algorithm would imply co-NP is included in NP which is unlikely

*Checking that a formula is satisfiable: NP, generate proof by providing a solution*

*Checking that a formula is unsafisfiable: co-NP, generating proof can be harder, in classical proof systems the shortest proof of unsatisfiability of an arbitrary formula can be exponentially long*

The algorithm you are looking for would mean all problems in co-NP have a short refutation, by providing a solution to the "opposite" formula. Therefore we are unaware of the existence of such an algorithm.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, it explains why solving is not possible in polynomial time, but it does not provide any reason why solving is a requirement for reversing the SAT answer.

Comment: @Ivo I don't understand what you mean by "solving is a requirement for reversing the SAT answer". This answer doesn't talk about *solving*, and membership in NP and co-NP isn't really related to being able to solve anything.

Comment: Expanding the answer a bit: A function $f$ with $f(\varphi) \in \overline{\mathrm{SAT}}$ iff $\varphi \in \mathrm{SAT}$ is a many-one reduction showing $\mathrm{SAT} \leq_\mathsf{P} \overline{\mathrm{SAT}}$. As $\overline{\mathrm{SAT}}$ is known to be $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete, the existence of such a reduction implies $\mathsf{coNP} \subseteq \mathsf{NP}$, which is an open question and seems rather unlikely given that if it were to be true, then $\mathsf{coNP} = \mathsf{NP}$ and thus a collapse of the polynomial hierarchy to the first level looks probable.

Comment: @JiK I meant solving as in deciding if it / is not in SAT. TO give an example with another problem called EVEN: given an integer, decide whether that integer is even. This question would ask "given an instance x, return an instance y not in EVEN iff the instance is in EVEN". An algorithm that can do that is y = x + 1, which works without knowing whether x is in EVEN or not. ...

Comment: ... In the same way, an algorithm might exist that can create an instance in SAT from an instance not in SAT and vice versa without knowing if the original instance is in SAT. This answer says it is (likely) not possible to know within polynomial time whether an instance is in SAT, but not why knowing that is required.

Comment: @Ivo What I meant is that I don't understand why you say _"it explains why solving is not possible in polynomial time"_ because this answer does not talk about solving at all.

Comment: @JiK I meant solving as in deciding if it / is not in SAT, i.e. "checking whether a formula is satisfiable"

Comment: @Ivo You wrote _"it explains why solving is not possible in polynomial time"_, and I don't understand why you think that, because the answer does not at all talk about deciding whether a formula is satisfiable in polynomial time or any time at all.

Comment: @Ivo The answer only talks about the hypothesized asymmetry of NP and co-NP, which would imply the asymmetry of SAT and UNSAT, and this answer does explain why that means a polynomial algoritm for the question is not likely to exist. There is nothing about algorithms that deciding whether a formula is satisfiable in this answer, NP and co-NP are not about algorithms that solve problems.

Comment: Seems like I misunderstood the answer before, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

yet we can't determined such a thing due to the fact that SAT is NP-hard and the "UNSAT" is co-Np-hard.

Answer (score -1):

There can't be such a polynomial-time algorithm that reliably inverts satisfiability unless P = NP.

If S is satisfiable, you can only make it unsatisfiable by adding constraints.  If S is unsatisfiable, you can only make it satisfiable by removing constraints.  By the law of the excluded middle S must be satisfiable or unsatisfiable, which means your algorithm must either add or remove constraints, which means that you must be able to determine whether S is satisfiable or unsatisfiable in polynomial time before you can decide what changes to make.  That is, you must have a polynomial-time algorithm that decides Boolean satisfiability as a necessary first step.

Comment: There are other ways to transform formulas into other formulas than just removing or adding constraints.

Comment: For example, if the problem is restricted to 2-CNF formulas, there is an obvious answer that gives a formula with just a 0 or 2 clauses, no matter the input formula size.

Comment: There are no other ways *that affect satisfiability or unsatisfiability*, which is the point of this exercise.  And your 2-CNF example just further illustrates my point in that there *is* a polynomial-time algorithm that decides satisfiability for 2-CNF formulas so you can decide what to do, and what you end up doing is removing or adding constraints.

Comment: I'm not following. If the input is $(x \vee y) \wedge (y \vee z) \wedge (z \vee x)$, which is satisfiable, a correct algorithm could output $(x \vee x) \wedge (\neg x \vee \neg x)$, which is unsatisfiable. Is this what you call "removing or adding constraints"?

Comment: Yes.  You have added a constraint that makes the formula unsatisfiable.

Comment: But you could also add a constraint that doesn't make the formula unsatisfiable. The algorithm doesn't need to know beforehand whether a constraint it adds makes the formula unsatisfiable. It could just remove some constraints according to some rule and then add some constraints according to some rule.

Comment: Those actions, whatever they are, are the same as adding or removing some constraint.  And those rules, whatever they are, must encode in them a polynomial-time decision procedure for Boolean satisfiability, otherwise the overall transformation procedure will not work for some formulas.  Since what you need to do to satisfiable and unsatisfiable formulas is different, you must decide satisfiability first.

Comment: Why would the rules need to encode a polynomial-time decision procedure for Boolean satisfiability?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107963/discussion-between-kyle-jones-and-jik).